# Configure an Elasticsearch mapping to match stemmed terms as well as unstemmed terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to setup stemming in my ES mapping. I pass the name of the stemming analyzer through the indexed document (de_analyzer)

I observe that the below mapping properly adds the stemmed terms to the index, but now I can no longer search for the unstemmed terms. No matches are returned. It seems that only the stemmed terms are indexed?

This is the index configuration showing the filter, index analyzer, search analyzer and field configuration.

What am I overseeing?

Thanks!

```
{
    "globalfashionmonitor": {
        "template": "myindex*",
        "settings": {
            "index.number_of_shards": 5,
            "default_search": "analyzer_search",
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "de_stem_filter": {
                        "type": "stemmer",
                        "name": "minimal_german"
                    }
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "analyzer_search": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer",
                    "filter": [
                        "icu_folding"
                    ]
                },
                "de_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "filter": [
                        "icu_normalizer",
                        "de_stop_filter",
                        "de_stem_filter",
                        "icu_folding"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "mappings": {
                "items": {
                    "_analyzer": {
                        "path": "use_analyzer"
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "summarizedArticle": {
                            "fields": {
                                "stemmed": {
                                    "index_analyzer": "de_analyzer",
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "index": "analyzed"
                                }
                            },
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the reason is that when passing the default document analyzer with  "_analyzer": { "path": "use_analyzer"}, only the index analyzer is set but not the search analyzer... little bit odd behaviour. I took a different route now.